# Dealing with a JSON.Net JArray in Python?

Tags: c#, python-2.7, json.net, ironpython

I'm using IronPython as a scripting language in my C# application. One of the "features" that I've implemented is the ability for a script to persist values, which are then exposed to the next script being executed. This is achieved by passing the value(s) to be stored to a C# class, exposed to the script by the "host" application. The code to store a value looks something like this:

```
store.set("xyz", 123)
```

('store' is the variable through which the C# object is exposed).

Internally the C# class stores these name/value pairs in a `Dictionary<string, object>`. When the script finishes executing it serialises the dictionary using Json.Net (`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)`) and writes the resulting string to file.

When the next script is run, the "host" C# application reads and deserialises the file (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(s)`) and exposes the name/value pairs to the script via the same C# class, which the script can access like this:

```
my_var = store.get("xyz")
```

This feature has been working fine with simple types such as ints and floats, but one of our users now needs to persist a list of `int`s. It works to a fashion - the list gets persisted and exposed to the next Python script, but at this point it is now a `JArray` type (something to do with Json.Net it seems). This doesn't play nicely with the Python code (which is expecting a list of `int`s).

I guess the simplest fix is to convert this JArray to a Python `int` list. But how?

Alternatively it would be nice if the issue could be "fixed" in the C# class (casting?), to avoid users from having to do this conversion in their scripts. However I don't want to change the de/serialisation process to the extent that it no longer reads users' existing data files. Thoughts?

Comment: could you provide an example of what the desired outcome would be and what you currently have (JSON)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution with only minimal impact on script authors. In my C# code, after deserialising the file, I go through the dictionary looking for items with a value of type `JArray`, and convert them to arrays:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

var keys = dict.Keys.ToList();
foreach (var key in keys)
{
   var jarray = dict[key] as JArray;
   if (jarray != null)
   {
      dict[key] = jarray.ToObject<object[]>();
   }
}
```

These arrays are then exposed to the Python script as before; as they are C# arrays the script authoer must convert to Python lists, which is trivial:

```
my_var = list(store.get("xyz"))
```